# How to sort multiple form field arrays in php?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, sorting

I have an array from a form submission:

```
Array
(
    [form_key] => 9juTLit5qQbaBb98
    [sku] => Array
        (
            [0] => AC25
            [1] => AC30
            [2] => AC31
        )

    [product] => Array
        (
            [0] => 95
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 101
        )

    [related_product] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
        )

    [qty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 2
        )

)
```

Is there a good way to sort it more like?

```
Array
(
    [form_key] => 9juTLit5qQbaBb98
    [0] => Array
        (
            [sku] => AC25
            [product] => 95
            [qty] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [sku] => AC30
            [product] => 100
            [qty] => 2
        )


    [2] => Array
        (
            [sku] => AC31
            [product] => 101
            [qty] => 2
        )

)
```

Comment: Be easier to change the form.

Comment: you can get the form to do that?

Comment: You could also always use jQuery to change the organization of each form value -- to match what you are desiring. Obviously, you will want to validate your input in your submission code, but you should be doing that anyways.

Comment: What does your form actually look like?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you indicated that you may be able to change the form, you could do something like this and get the desired array structure:

```
<input type="text" name="data[0][sku]">
<input type="text" name="data[0][product]">
<input type="text" name="data[0][qty]">

<input type="text" name="data[1][sku]">
<input type="text" name="data[1][product]">
<input type="text" name="data[1][qty]">
```

The array will be in `$_POST['data']` which is handy for looping since it is isolated from `form_key`, `submit` etc...

Comment: This solution is interesting because you don't need extra overhead when processing the submitted data to arrange the data.

Comment: Yes - this is exactly what I should be doing. I can easily set an iterator before the products output loop in the form. thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Pick one field to loop over, then grab the values from the other fields:

```
foreach($data['sku'] as $key=>$sku){
    $product = $data['product'][$key];
    $related_product = $data['related_product'][$key];
    $qty = $data['qty'][$key];
}
```

Then you can build a new array, or do whatever with the values.

```
$newArray[] = array(
    'sku' => $sku,
    'product' => $product,
    'related_product' => $related_product,
    'qty' => $qty
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Quite basic example but should work with more complicate data set

```
$rs = [];
foreach($_POST as $k1=>$elem) {
    if(is_array($elem)) {
        foreach($elem as $k2=>$value) {
            $rs[$k2][$k1] = $value;
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $newArray = [];
    foreach ($array as $mainKey => $value ) {
        foreach($value as $subKey => $subValue) {
            $newArray[$subKey][$mainKey] = $subValue;
        }
    }

    print_r($newArray);
```